# Am I doing this the Objective-C way? (no static class variables)

Tags: objective-c

OK, imagine I have a Zoo, and I only want it to contain animals of a certain colour.  I have a Zoo object, which has a colour property (a char, in this example, could just as well be an object of some sort).  I also have an Animal class, which I never instantiate (I still think of it as being abstract, I'm java) because I extend it with animal types.

I want to check whether I can add a particular animal type to my zoo.  I don't like the idea of making colour a property of Animal and having to instantiate each Animal before I can check whether I can have one.  Seems to me I want colour t be a class variable of Animal rather than an instance variable, at least that's how I'd have done it in Java, but I get that the style is quite different.

My solution was:

in ZooController:

```
if([zoo canAddAnimalOfType:[Elephant class]])
{
     [zoo addAnimal:([Elephant animal])];
}
```

and in Zoo:

```
@property char colour;

- (BOOL)canAddAnimalOfType:(Class)animalType
{
    if([animalType colour] == colour)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

and here was my solution to lack of class variables in Animal (which Elephant extends):

```
+(char)colour
{
    return 'n';
}
```

So in effect I'm using a class method to encapsulate a class variable, which seems kinda messy to me.  My question is, is this the Objective C way?  If not, what would be?

Thanks

Comment: You can remove the parenthesis in the first code snippet, '([Elephant class])'. They are extraneous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the Objective-C way (although the example scenario is questionable).  When you have a value that is guaranteed to be the same for all instances of a class, but may change depending on subclass, use a class method to return the value.  (This is not the only use of class methods.)

Here are some examples from Apple's frameworks.  There are others.

- [`+[UIView layerClass]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/cc8a92/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/layerClass)
- [`+[UIView requiresConstraintBasedLayout]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW162)
- [`+[NSObject classFallbacksForKeyedArchiver]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-BBCDDFJF)
- [`+[NSObject classForKeyedUnarchiver]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBDEDFH)
- [`+[NSObject accessInstanceVariablesDirectly]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-CJBJCGFH)
- [`+[NSValueTransformer allowsReverseTransformation]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001922-BAJCCFEI)
- [`+[NSValueTransformer transformedValueClass]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001922-BAJHJBDI)
- [`+[NSCell defaultFocusRingType]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000074-BBCGCGCB)
- [`+[NSCell defaultMenu]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000074-defaultMenu)
- [`+[NSCell prefersTrackingUntilMouseUp]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000074-prefersTrackingUntilMouseUp)
- [`+[NSDocument autosavesDrafts]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsdocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-SW73)
- [`+[NSDocument autosavesInPlace]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsdocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-SW45)

Comment: `layerClass` should be seen as a special case; the exception and not the rule. Putting getters as class methods generally is not recommended, properties is normally preferred.

Comment: I'm confused - a property was my first thought, but doesn't the class have to be instantiated to hold a property?  How can you have a class property (as opposed to an instance property)?

Comment: Classes in Objective-C cannot have properties, because the language syntax provides no way to declare them.  However, you can call no-argument class methods using dot notation, like you would for properties: `Class c = UIView.layerClass;` is perfectly valid.  I usually don't do that just because Xcode won't autocomplete the method name after `UIView.`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, that looks wrong to me. For this scenario, class methods feel ugly. I would instantiate the Elephant object and then test if that instance could go in the zoo. Why? Because you might want Elephants to have more than just one colour. Rather than subclassing for each different variant, you can simply set @property's on each instance and pass the instance to the zoo to test.

If initialising an Animal object is very expensive, you could use a slightly-different pattern. Create a lightweight class called an AnimalDescriptor, which you can instantiate to describe an animal's properties rather than the actual object. If the test passes, then use the descriptor to create a full object.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right there, the animals example is just one I made up, it's not really what I'm doing.  With what I'm doing the variable is always fixed for each subclass.